# Why is NW.SHELL only wokring in root DIR of app?

Tags: javascript, nwjs

For some reason NW.SHELL fuctions are only working for files in root folder of my app. It wont let me use an absolute path or a relative path. Example "/relative/path/text.txt" or D:/relative/path/text.txt however text.txt will work with NW.SHELL function as long as the text file is in the same root DIR obviously.

This applies to both of these. What can i do to get relative or absolute paths to work? preferably relative paths. The nature of my program relative would be most functional.

```
nw.Shell.showItemInFolder('test.txt');
nw.Shell.openItem('test.txt');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using version 0.65.0 of NW.js, it *does* work with absolute paths.

```js
const path = require('path');
nw.Shell.openItem(path.resolve('./test.txt'));
```

If that doesn't work, `test.txt` is not in the current working directory.

Comment: Does that work the same with InFolder? I just tried it with an onclick to call the function in my js script and it still didnt do anything,

Comment: function OpenFolder1() {
    const path = require('path');
    nw.Shell.showItemInFolder(path.resolve('D:\SECURE DRIVE\SYSTEM FOLDER\DOCUMENTS\DOCUMENTS.NFO'));
}

Comment: I still cant get it to work

Comment: Yes, it works with both `openItem()` and `showItemInFolder()`. If it doesn't work, something else in your code is broken. Look at the console when you click your button and read the error message...

Comment: Console as in my Visual Studio Console or some NWJS console idk how to do that second one.

Comment: DEBUG LOG: [0603/170627.910:ERROR:zip_reader.cc(132)] Cannot open ZIP from file handle 00000000000001EC
[0603/170627.910:ERROR:zip.cc(202)] Cannot open ZIP from file handle 00000000000001EC

Comment: This is what returns after i click on it which makes no sense aha what do zips have to do with anything with showing a document in file folder? I was only using DOCUMENTS.NFO as a shortcut basically to open the documents folder when i click on the Documents button.

Comment: Figured it out bro! DONT USE BACKSLASHES! Use forward slashes even though the true file path uses backslashes. I noticed the backslashes were white while the rest of the typed path was orange and when i put forward slash it turned the slash orange. Its all working now. Thank you. That could possibly be why my original code in the question wasn't working as well.